# Moq setup for generic method - cannot be used as type parameter T

Tags: c#, generics, moq

I'm trying to mock this method.

```cs
Task<Response> SendTemplatedEmail<T>(TemplatedEmail<T> templatedEmail, EmailRecipient<T> recipient)
            where T : TemplateData;
```

This is the closest I've got that makes logical sense to me.

```
this.mockSender.Setup(x => x.SendTemplatedEmail<It.IsSubtype<TemplateData>>(It.IsAny<It.IsSubtype<TemplateData>>, It.IsAny<It.IsSubtype<TemplateData>>));
```

But I get the following error:

CS0311: The type `TemplatedEmail<Moq.It.Is.IsSubtype<TemplateData>>` cannot be used as type parameter `'T'` in the generic type or method `IEmailSender.SendTemplatedEmail<T>` ( `TemplatedEmail<T>`, `EmailRecipient<T>>)`' There is no implicit reference conversion from '`TemplateEmail<Moq.It.IsSubtype<TemplateData>>` to `TemplateData`)

Here are the relevant class.

```
  public class TemplatedEmail<T>
        where T : TemplateData
    { ... }
```

In plain English, the method takes a `templatedEmail` parameter of type `TemplatedEmail<T>` where `T` is a subclass of `TemplateData`. It also takes second generic parameter `EmailRecipient` of the same type `T`.

Answer (score -1):

```
this.mockSender.Setup(
                x => x.SendTemplatedEmail<IsTemplateData<TemplateData>>(
                    It.IsAny<TemplatedEmail<IsTemplateData<TemplateData>>>(),
                    It.IsAny<EmailRecipient<IsTemplateData<TemplateData>>>()));
```

From: https://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20200605-MatchingGenericTypeArgumentsWithMoq.html

Comment: Could you please describe how did you solve your problem? *Sharing the code is good, describing the solution is awesome.*